# Google Drive PHP API pagination not working when using different requests

Tags: php, laravel, google-drive-api

I'm using Google Drive PHP API in a Laravel (v9.0) project. Regarding the pagination, I wish the following flow:

1. The first page of files is fetched and returned to the frontend;
2. When then user scrolls to the bottom of the page, the frontend requests the next page of files;
3. The backend receives the request and fetches from Google Drive API the appropriate page.

The problem I'm facing is that when the frontend requests the next page (in the example bellow, `pageToken` has the value of `nextPageToken` from previous Google Drive call), Google will raise an error: `code: 400, message: Invalid Value, location: pageToken`. Bellow is the code I'm using:

```php
$pageToken = request()->input('pageToken');

$optParams = [
    'q' => '' . $parentQuery,
    'pageSize' => $paginateSize,
    'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, parents)',
];

if ($pageToken) {
    $optParams['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
}

$response = $this->service->files->listFiles($optParams);
```

However, if I fetch all pages in the backend, before returning them, it seems to work:

```php
$optParams = [
    'q' => '' . $parentQuery,
    'pageSize' => $paginateSize,
    'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, parents)',
];

$files = [];

do {
    $results = $this->service->files->listFiles($optParams);

    $files = array_merge($files, $results->getFiles());

    $pageToken = $results->getNextPageToken();

    if ($pageToken) {
        $optParams['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
    }

} while ($pageToken);
```

I might have misunderstood the way pagination is meant to be used in Google Drive API, but is there a way to paginate things like in my first example?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the pageToken value is valid by using the **isset** and **empty** functions

```
$pageToken = request()->input('pageToken');

$optParams = [
    'q' => '' . $parentQuery,
    'pageSize' => $paginateSize,
    'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, parents)',
];

if (isset($pageToken) && !empty($pageToken)) {
    $optParams['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
}

$response = $this->service->files->listFiles($optParams);
```